# Firebase Realtime database rule to avoid duplicate value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following structure in Firebase Realtime database :

```
{
  "e_pass": [
    {
      "address": "M12, AV Colony",
      "epass_id": "RPR/0003",
      "epass_vehicle_id": "na",
      "from_city": "Raipur",
      "from_date": "31-03-2020",
      "from_district": "Raipur",
      "from_location": "AV Colony Mowa",
      "isApproved": "1",
      "mobile_number": "99999999",
      "time_stamp": 1585577315093,
      "user_name": "John Doe",
      "vehicle_number": "CG04HX1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to apply the following rule to prevent the duplication of key `mobile_number`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "e_pass": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": {
        "$mobile_number": {
          ".write" : "!data.parent().hasChild($mobile_number)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it keeps failing. What should be the rule?

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have your data structure now, it's not possible.  In general, it's not possible to use security rules to ensure uniqueness of child values among sibling nodes.

Your alternative is to write the value that should be unique as a node name (not a child value) somewhere else in the database that can be queried by security rules to check for existence.

For example, if you had a node called "mobile_numbers", you could populate children under it every time a new e_pass child is added:

```
"mobile_numbers": {
    "99999999": true
}
```

Then you check for its existence in a rule like this:

```
root.child('mobile_numbers').hasChild($mobile_number)
```